# NSCollectionView drawing issue when scrolling

Tags: cocoa, scroll, updating, nscollectionview

I have a strange problem that exists only on one computer during testing. In my developer laptop its ok.

When scrolling, dragging it makes no updated.

[image: NSCollectionView scroll]

There is no custom drawing code, only NSCollectionView & NSCollectionView items subclasses with dragging items support, what's the problem?

Comment: You mean to say when you scroll down your collection view data is not refreshed right?

Comment: yes, it draws old state and state after scroll on the same place

Comment: well one thing is there you can post notification when you scroll as it is scrollview predefined notification. Inside that you can refersh you view.  -(void) viewDidLoad { [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(boundsDidChange:) name:NSViewBoundsDidChangeNotification object:[yourscrollview contentView]];                 and then write these line in method where you need to send notification [[yourscrollview contentView]setPostsBoundsChangedNotifications:YES];

Comment: After that on last implement these method boundsDidChange inisde that write some reload collection view code